# Equivalence of Two Polytopes

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, polytopes

I am trying to understand more about combinatorics and geometry of polytopes.  If we create a pair of polytopes as below, they have the same number of facets (seven each) and they are combinatorially isomorphic.

Although the faces have different sizes when you compare the two, is it trivial that the facets of the first one are in one-to-one correspondence with the facets of the second polytope?  If so, how does one find the map which creates the second polytope from the first one, is it some type of re-scaling of coordinates?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [zonohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonohedron).

Comment: Are you unhappy with the map that just sends each vertex on the first polytope the coordinates of a unique vertex in the second polytope? For example if the vertex sets are labeled: $\{a,b,c,d \}$ and $\{e,f,g,h\}$ we can map $a$ to $e$, $b$ to $f$, etc. and this is a bijective map. Are you looking for like a transformation perhaps?

Comment: @RobertMurray If the facets of a polytope $A$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the members of a finite set $X$ and the facets of a polytope $B$ are also in one-to-one correspondence with the members of $X$ (ie. both polytopes have the same number of facets), under what circumstances are we able to state that the two polytopes are isomorphic?

Comment: Do you want the resp. faces of the second polytope remain parallel to the faces of the first one ?

Comment: Yes, I think they would need to remain parallel.

Comment: If you look one dimension less, i.e., dimension 2, there is a concept called a ["straight skeleton"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) (which can be extended to 3D as said in this article) with the "roof paradigm" : you take one of the 2D shapes (polygon) as the border of the roof, and any "shrinked" second shape  (more or less in the sense you want) is a so-called "level-set" of your roof (at least until two "slopes" merge). Please note that the roof has not necessarily sides with the same slope, giving a large degree of freedom.

Comment: If you have any comment on my comment, don't forget to prefix it by my pseudo. Otherwise, I will not be "triggered".

Comment: @JeanMarie I am still thinking about your suggestion.  I am not sure it would work in my case, as I think I need the slopes of the faces to remain the same after the transformation.

Comment: The comparison between polytopes that you seems to ask for is "combinatorial equivalence" (the gold standard for comparing polytopes combinatorially). To each polytope one can associate a so-called [face-lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#The_face_lattice). $P$ and $Q$ being combinatorially equivalent means that their face lattices are isomorphic. The specific polytopes that you show are also "normally equivalent" (i.e. their faces are parallel). Also, in 3D you don't need the face-lattices, but it is sufficient to compare the edge graphs.

Answer (score 1):

If neither edge sizes nor face parallelness are kept, the only rescue is the abstract polytopal incidence structure, either being outlayed as an incidence matrix (running on all the various elements, i.e. all vertices, edges, faces; cf. https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/explain/incmat.htm), or, equivalently, the abstract polytopal Hasse diagram, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram). For, if these would coincide between the given 2 polytopes, then they definitely are equivalent as abstract polytopes too.

--- rk